# X11/Gnome/TrackPoint: custom button mapping not working

Tags: mouse, xorg, arch-linux, gnome3

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T430s running with Arch Linux/Gnome 3.6 and I want to switch the left and right button of the trackpoint buttons (the upper ones). I can switch the left/right buttons of ALL mouses (trackpoint/touchpad/bluetooth mouses/usb mouses etc) with the gnome control center no problem, but not specifically for the trackpoint.

When I enter

```
xinput set-button-map 14 3 2 1 4 5 6 7
```

where 14 is the current xinput list device id of my trackpoint, everything is fine until I reboot, which also changes the device id somehow. It is possible to specify the device by name:

```
xinput set-button-map "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" 3 2 1 4 5 6 7
```

but later I found out that this setting is lost after suspend. So I tried and created a x11 conf:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-trackpoint.conf
```

with the content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "trackpoint"
    MatchProduct    "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "ButtonMapping"  "3 2 1 4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

but that is not working. It seems like this configuration is loaded before gnome and gnome changes everything back. So how do I do this?

Comment: You could try adding the xinput command to your .bashrc file, not elegant but it might work.

Comment: yes but what do I put in for the id (which changes on reboot, as I wrote) ?

Comment: I added `xinput set-button-map "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" 3 2 1 4 5 6 7` to my gnome session. It does the trick, but it is ugly. As i learned the gnome settings daemon overrides xorg settings.

Comment: edit: xinput setting is lost after suspend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/48955/how-can-i-configure-a-specific-usb-mouse-model-as-left-handed and http://ubuntuforums.org/printthread.php?t=1746468&pp=10&page=1 I gather that you might be missing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false
```

or (alternatively)

> Then, once you run gconf-editor, from the GUI, navigate to
>
> ```
> apps > gnome_settings_daemon > plugins > mouse
> ```
>
> and uncheck the box for "active".

because that's

> ... not the end of the story, however, as Natty still uses
>   gnome-settings-daemon to control mouse and keyboard settings. Usually,
>   this is smart enough to get out of the way, but when it comes to mice,
>   (specifically buttons) it will attempt to automatically ensure that
>   your primary and secondary buttons are mapped to the system-wide left
>   or right handed layout. In this particular case, we don't want that,
>   so we need to turn this bit of functionality off.

Either of the above should work. Let me know if it doesn't. Good luck!